# Run script on load and on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

So i am creating a google custom search that has a checkbox that when checked, will cause a diffrent google custom search to be used, Here is the code im using and here is my issue. I dont know if the script is run when i hit search, therefore not getting the new change. So when i check the box i want the script to re run again, but i also what the script to run on load.

```
    <script>
    (function() {
     if (jQuery('#sota').is(':checked')) {var cx = '001285214241856463016:s82pvcctjhm';} else {var cx ='001285214241856463016:zrd6kn8chti';}
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
    </script>
    <form class="sech">
        <input id="sota" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Search Only Technologies Available For Licensing
    </form>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: Does'nt really matter if you run the function on change event of a checkbox. Once an external script is loaded, you can't remove it ?

Comment: Can i not overwrite it by running the script again below with the updated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a function on load:

```
window.onload = function() {
  //do stuff
}
```

To run on checking the checkbox

```
<input id="sota" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" onchange="chgFn(this)">
<script>
function chgFn(chkBox) {
  if(chkBox.checked){
      //do stuff
  }
}
</script>
```